# In AutocompleteSupportFragment want show only airport suggestion?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

```
final AutocompleteSupportFragment destination_autocomplete =
            (AutocompleteSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.etxt_des_addressnew);
    destination_autocomplete.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field.ID, com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field.NAME, com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field.ADDRESS
            , com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.Field.LAT_LNG));
    destination_autocomplete.setCountry(mPresenter.getLocation_Filter(this));
   ((EditText)destination_autocomplete.getView().findViewById(R.id.etxt_des_addressnew)).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    destination_autocomplete.a.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    destination_autocomplete.a.setTextSize(14.0f);
    destination_autocomplete.a.setHint(getResources().getString(R.string.Please_Enter_Your_Destination));
```

`Place.TYPE_AIRPORT` I don't know where I have to put this and also I want syntax for this.

Comment: Place.TYPE_AIRPORT i dont know where i have to put and alos i want syntax for this

Comment: @Lalit Fauzdar can you help me in above issue